# How to recover Windows 10 from C: Partition?

Tags: windows, backup, restore

Ok, brother-in-law accidentally put the wrong power cord!

Windows 10 PC no longer boots and the Windows system partitions are foobar.

The C: drive looks completely intact.

So is there a way to recreate the system from that C: drive? I have extra drives to copy stuff back and forth if required and extra PCs.

Tried all sorts of windows commands to recreate systems partitions but just cant get it to boot :-(

Comment: The wrong power cord more than likely caused hardware failures, no recovery for that.

Comment: "Intact" like "not gone up in smoke"?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the windows system partitions don't work anymore? This could be a hardware issue (more likely in your case, because you mentioned the incorrect power cord thing).

In any case, if your system does indeed boot up and perform POST, try accessing the BIOS (check your motherboard's instruction manual ). If you can, make a Windows Recovery drive using a pen drive with more than 8GB of storage using one of your other PCs. Boot to this device using your BIOS, and try performing a system repair or factory reset.

Comment: Yes, I can indeed POST, and as a matter of fact created a Windows Media Creation Tool to boot to Windows 10 "Installer". At the main screen selected "Repair Installation", and Command Prompt to "try" to recreate EFI and MSR partitions, but can't get it to boot to the original C: drive.

I did not perform a Factory reset because my understanding is that it would delete all my installed programs, and only keep the data files.

Am I incorrect?